# Is there a way to remove/or edit close button from ctools modal windows on drupal?

Tags: jquery, css, drupal, drupal-7

Basically that is the question

"Is there a way to remove/or edit close button from ctools modal windows on drupal?"

I have a windows, and I want get rid of the icon on the top right and add some text ("CLOSE") or at least get rid of that button.

This is my window

[image: Modal Window]

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use [hook_css_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7) to achieve this.

You can find an example [here](https://gist.github.com/malcomio/8556964).

Hope that helps.